# Angular-Template: How to display the row item as a normal table row

Tags: angular, html-table, angular2-template

I have the parent component template containing a table

```
<table> 
   <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
                <th>Col 5</th>
                <th>Col 6</th>
                <th>Col 7</th>                         
            </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
          <app-child-component [rows]="rows"></app-child-component>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Child component template

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item let-i="index" [ngForOf]="row">
  <tr>     
      <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value3}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value4}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value5}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value6}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value7}}</td>
</tr>
</ng-template>
```

Results:

[image: Table]

My question is how can display as a normal table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute selector for your child component:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'tbody[app-child]',
  template: `
    <tr *ngFor="let item of rows">    
        <td></td> 
        <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value3}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value4}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value5}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value6}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value7}}</td>
    </tr>
  `
})
export class AppChildComponent  {
```

now parent template should look like:

```typescript
<tbody app-child [rows]="rows"></tbody>
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/hrELndcWuVZH4UCKbjfx?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi @yurzui, it works. Thanks so much. However, could you tell me what the reason is?

Comment: When you use tag selector you get invalid html. `tbody` tag can't have `app-child-component` as child node

Comment: Yuruzi what do you mean by invalid html? Isnt his ngtemplate woild produce a series of table rows?

Comment: @RoyiNamir tbody can only contain tr elements https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: I know but isnt that ngtemplate is changed to the result of ngfor for that ngtemplate which produces tr's?

Comment: @RoyiNamir you missed app-child-component tag that will be created for angular component. In my solution I use existing tbody tag and don't produce other custom tag

Comment: Yuruzi I think im missing something here. Inside tbody there is a custom tag but that tag is compiled to bunch of tr's so it suppose to be valid. No?

Comment: Oh @yurzui Now I see. I forgot that component name is ALSO rendered not jsut the calculated elements. BTW in angular1 there was a solution for not rendering the component tag itself. What is the solution in ng4 ? https://i.imgur.com/KPdS1w0.jpg